# Append string to existing string values in AWS dynamo db table using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using boto3 to update AWS dynamo db table.

Requirement is to append 'abctest1.sh' to existing value for key 'init_script_name'. That means the updated value for 'init_script_name' should be 'abctest.sh,abctest1.sh' for all items in the dynamo db table.

```
"system_configuration": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "name": {
            "S": "Desktop"
          },
          "configuration": {
            "L": [
              {
                "M": {
                  "key": {
                    "S": "DiskSize"
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "S": "RootVolume"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "M": {
                  "key": {
                    "S": "init_script_name"
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "S": "abctest.sh"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried below code block to update the key. But it is replacing existing 'abctest.sh' with abctest1.sh, instead of appending or concatenating existing value with new value

```
updResponse=dyd.update_item(TableName='test1',
                            Key={
                                "name":{"S":"Linux"}
                                },
                            UpdateExpression="SET #sys_config[0].#config[1].#val= :updVal",
                            ExpressionAttributeNames={"#sys_config": "system_configuration",
                                                      "#config":"configuration",
                                                      "#val":"value" },
                            ExpressionAttributeValues={":updVal": {"S":"abctest1.sh"}}
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo doesn't have a concat string functionality like this. You can increment  numbers or add items to a *list or map* but not a string. Strings are replace only

see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html

You will need to get a copy of the item first then update that copy and push the updated copy. Ie: get the item, store as a dict. Update the key you need to update with the new value + old value, then UpdateItem with this new concatted key.

If you have to do more than a few you definitely want to look into the batch writing: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#batch-writing

If this is a task you will be performing a lot, you might be better served by changing that from a "S" string to a "L" list

```
 {"L": [ { "S": "abctest1.sh" },{ "S": "abctest2.sh" }]}}
```